# How can I position a single boxplot in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to position a single boxplot at a custom position like so:

```
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np
a=np.random.randn(1000)
plt.boxplot(a, positions=np.array([2.]))
```

but it always appears at 1. Note that `plt.violinplot(a, positions=np.array([2.]))` works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is plotted at the correct position, it's just that the label on the axis is still set to 1.  You can see this if you try to plot something else on the axes.  For instance, if you do `pyplot.plot([1, 2, 3], [3, 0, -3])` you will see that the middle of line crosses through the middle of the boxplot.

This means things will show up in the right places if you're plotting other stuff on the same axes as the boxplot.  If you're not plotting anything else on the same axes, it doesn't really matter where the boxes are actually located; you can just set the labels directly by using the `labels` argument to `boxplot`.

Comment: ok, so it does plot it at the right location, just the label is wrong. I guess I was confused because the violinplot works nicely. Would be nice if that was consistent.